# What is CARD32 data type used in xserver code?

Tags: xorg, xserver

What is CARD32 data-type and where is it defined? I am reading xserver code and am unable to find definitions for CARD data type.

Comment: unsigned 4 byte (32 bit) int

Comment: https://code.woboq.org/gtk/include/X11/X.h.html#82

Comment: Thank you this helped.Also thanks for pointing to the code browser woboq.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the comments on the post cite the wrong code snippet for justification, I wanted to give a proper answer.

As already noted `CARD32` is an **unsigned 32 bit integer**.

The type is defined in a C header file in `X11/Xmd.h` ([GitHub Permalink](https://github.com/freedesktop/xorg-xorgproto/blob/a0ed054ee2c334941dfe9eaa7bcfdbbe6907e1b5/include/X11/Xmd.h) as of 8th Sept. 2021).
Here is the revelant excerpt:

```c
# ifdef LONG64
typedef unsigned long CARD64;
typedef unsigned int CARD32;
# else
typedef unsigned long long CARD64;
typedef unsigned long CARD32;
# endif
```

Further up, the `LONG64` macro is defined only for 64-bit architectures. So, `CARD32` is a `unsigned int` on 64-bit architectures and `unsigned long` everywhere else.